# Checking to see if a property exists without throwing exception yii2

Tags: yii2

Depending on database result, some properties of my object may be populated or not.

Lets say I have a *task* object and if there is a message for it, so it has the `$message` property populated:

```
if($task->message === null)
        throw new ErrorException('what the ...');
```

The problem is, whenever I want to check if this property is populated (accessing it), it throws an *Getting unknown property* exception and the execution terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try with isset

```
if (isset($task->message ))   {
  // your code for is setted 

} else {

  // your code for not setted 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try-catch* block also works:

```
use yii\base\Exception;

[...]

try {

  echo $task->message;

} catch (Exception $e) { 
  // stuff
}
```

Comment: it also worked. thanks, at first i was testing with yii\base\ErrorException, and it wasn't fetching